# visualizar documentos pdf en el navagador con Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

tengo una pagina web en la que tengo un boton en una tabla de registros que me captura el id del registro y me traer el valor de la ruta donde esta guardado el archivo que corresponde con dicho registro, usando el siguiente codigo funciona bien en el servidor local.

```
$(".tablas").on("click",".btnImprimirDoc",function(){

  var ruta =$(this).attr("ruta");

  window.open(ruta, "_blank");

})
```

la ruta generada seria ejemplo hosting.com/reclamos/vistas/reclamos/1/6517-40539624-24-3-2020.pdf

este codigo me abre el archivo en otra ventana del navegador en el servidor local funciona perfecto, pero al subir el proyecto al hosting, me da este error 404 Error. Page Not Found. el archivo esta en el hosting en la ruta correcta. y desde el filemanager del cpanel lo puedo ver.

hay otra forma de poder visualizar el archivo pdf.

tengo un archivo .htaccess que me ayuda a proteger los archivos del directorio, pero el mismo no me genera problemas en el servidor local

Comment: El problema mismo te da la solución, error 404, page not found, si hay un 404 es porque, o hay mal una ruta o la pagina no existe. de lo contrario no apareceria el error.